# how do I download file(csv) form URL and save in my google drive

Tags: google-apps-script

how do I download file form URL (CSV) (Email Logged in Proacted URL) and save it in my google drive ( URL Location: G-Sheet >> Sheet1>>"G2" Cell)

Can anyone help me with the google script?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native function importdata.

[=importdata(url)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335)